# Source transformation with impedance being inductor or capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, current-source, voltage-source

I found a presentation that states the following about source transformation when the impedance is capacitive/inductive:

[image: Source Transformation - Presentation]

While electrical circuits books, like Nilsson's, says:
[image: Source Transformation - Nilsson]

---

If I transform the upper-right circuit of the first image to the upper-left, assuming that, for example:
$$i_s(t)=cos(\omega t)$$
$$L_p=L_s=L$$

By the first image, I have:
$$e_s(t)=L\dfrac{d(i_s(t))}{dt}=-\omega L \cdot sin (\omega t)$$

By the second:
$$e_s(t)=Z_L \cdot I_s=j \omega L \cdot cos(\omega t)$$

---

### Is the first figure's method incorrect or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint: Your final equation mixes up phasor notation and time-domain notation. If you want to compare it to the next-to-last equation, you should put it all in time domain.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I think I realized the error. I'm going to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the error was mine. As @The Photon noted, I'm mixing phasor notation (frequency domain) with time domain notation.

---

In time domain, we have (as pointed in the question):

$$i_s(t)=cos(\omega t)$$

$$e_s(t)=L\dfrac{d(i_s(t))}{dt}=-\omega L \cdot sin (\omega t)$$

---

Going from the **time domain** to the frequency domain (**phasor** notation):
$$i_s(t)=cos(\omega t) \iff I_s=1 \space \angle \space 0 $$

---

In frequency domain, we have:
$$I_s=1 \space \angle \space 0 $$
$$E_s=Z_L \cdot I_s=j \omega L \cdot 1 \space \angle \space 0$$

Remembering that: 
$$ j\omega L = \sqrt{0^2 +(\omega L)^2} \angle \space atan2 \space (\omega L,0)
 = \omega L \space \angle \space \frac{\pi}{2}$$
        *(Note: here I am converting from the **rectangular phasor** form to the **polar phasor** form)*

Thus, we can write:
$$E_s=Z_L \cdot I_s=\left (\omega L \space \angle \space \frac{\pi}{2} \right)  \cdot \left( 1 \space \angle \space 0 \right)= \omega L \space \angle \space \frac{\pi}{2}$$

---

Going from frequency domain (**phasor** notation) to **time domain**:
$$ E_s = \omega L \space \angle \space \frac{\pi}{2} \iff e_s(t)= \omega L \cdot cos \left( \omega t + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =-\omega L \cdot sin(\omega t) $$

---

### Therefore, both methods produce the same result.

---

Note - Remembering that from frequency to time domain we have:
$$ j \omega \iff \frac{d}{dt} $$

We can see that:
$$E_s=Z_L \cdot I_s = j \omega L \cdot I_s = L \cdot (j \omega I_s) \iff L\frac{d(i_s(t))}{dt}=e_s (t)$$